# Redirect_to and return twice in the same action in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

I have the following code:

```
def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    if !current_user.posts.include?(@post)
      permission_denied
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html  # edit.html.erb
      format.json  { render :json => @post }
    end
end

 def permission_denied
    flash[:notice] = 'Sorry, you are not authorized to access that page.'
    redirect_to root_url
 end
```

How could adapt this code, so it doesn't show me the "Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action" . I have tried adding "and return" to `redirect_to root_url and return`, but I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return from the edit action:

```
def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  return permission_denied if !current_user.posts.include?(@post)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html  # edit.html.erb
    format.json  { render :json => @post }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This actually raised another doubt, which I have asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880341/respond-to-and-redirect-in-the-same-action-in-rails

Comment: @HommerSmith, you're welcome. In your other question you don't have to worry about that. It's an if/else, so it either one or the other. Never both.