# Respond_to and redirect in the same action in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, render

In the Update action of Rails controllers usually there is code that looks like this:

```
def update
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  if @book.update_attributes(params[:book])
    redirect_to(@book)
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

In the else case, this will render the edit template.  But what if I wanted to use a respond_to, exactly the same way that I have in the edit action, as:

```
def update
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  if @book.update_attributes(params[:book])
    redirect_to(@book)
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html  # edit.html.erb
      format.json  { render :json => @team }
    end
  end
end
```

So, if the Update fails, be sure you are returning a json or html depending on the requested format.  Does that makes sense? If so, how would you avoid the error: "Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action"

Comment: You don't have to be afraid of "Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action" in this case, because it's either one or the other. Never both.

Answer (score 3):

Makes sense to me. The answer should be simple, just `return` after `redirect_to`.

```
def update
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  if @book.update_attributes(params[:book])
    redirect_to(@book)
    return
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html  # edit.html.erb
      format.json  { render :json => @team }
    end
  end
end
```

Not sure exactly how you're rendering multiple times, but assuming you are, a well-placed `return` should tell RAILS to stop processing any further renders after redirecting. If that's all true, it's likely that there's an `after_filter` interfering from somewhere.